# Building a symbol name and then requesting it in Tradingview

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to calculate the dollar value of a crypto currency that I'm viewing in Tradingview. An example would be ETHBTC. The intention of the script is to determine the currency of the graph (BTC) and then lookup BTCUSD getting a result of $40 000 for example. However, the script needs to accommodate the case when the graph being viewed is BTCUSD. In that case the currency is USD and therefor the USD dollar value should be $1. This script attempts to achieve this:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")


//Looking up the currency of current graph, ie ETHBTC or example 2, BTCUSD
theCurrency = syminfo.currency    // returns BTC or example 2 USD
theSymbol = theCurrency + "USD" // creates BTCUSD or incorrectly USDUSD
curUSDValue = 1.0
if (theSymbol == "USDUSD")
    curUSDValue := 1.0   //accomodate use case where currrecny is already USD
else
    curUSDValue := request.security(theSymbol, 'D', close)  //looks up price for BTCUSD

plot(curUSDValue)
```

Pinescript doesn't allow a lookup of the security in an if / conditional statement as the script above returns this error:

Cannot call 'request.*()' function inside 'if', 'switch' or 'for'

Any suggestions on how to work around this Pinescript limitation?

Answer (score 0):

You can never use `request.security()` inside an `if`. There's no way around that.
However, a rate conversion script already exists. See [Rate Converter](https://www.tradingview.com/script/UWqsUHAE-Rate-Converter/). You could take that as a starting point.